# List doesn't show data

Tags: android, arrays, listview, arraylist, parse-platform

I have strings stored (objectIDs) in my internal storage. When I want to display the list of the IDs saved it works, however when I try to get the Names from Parse.com It doesn't show up on the list.
This shows ObjectIds:

```
public class UserListForHistory extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list_for_history);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("NotificationIDs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> myStrings = settings.getStringSet("myStrings", new HashSet<String>());

    ListView idList;
    List<String> idListData;
    idListData = new ArrayList<String>();
    idList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    for(String userIds : myStrings){

        idListData.add(userIds);

    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, idListData);
    idList.setAdapter(str);


}
```

However when add this to "for" It doesn't display anything in the list! But it does display all on the names in logcat. Anyone see the problem?

```
public class UserListForHistory extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_list_for_history);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("NotificationIDs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> myStrings = settings.getStringSet("myStrings", new HashSet<String>());

    final ListView idList;
    final List<String> idListData;
    idListData = new ArrayList<>();
    idList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    for(String userIds : myStrings) {

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
        query.getInBackground(userIds, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                String name = parseObject.getString("fullname");
                Log.d("These are the names: ", name);

                idListData.add(name);
            }
        });

    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, idListData);
    idList.setAdapter(str);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls inside this for loop:

```
for(String userIds : myStrings) {
    query.getInBackground(userIds, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            String name = parseObject.getString("fullname");
            Log.d("These are the names: ", name);

            idListData.add(name);
        }
    });
}
```

are asynchronous, which means that `idListData` is still empty when your code reaches the following lines:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, idListData);
idList.setAdapter(str);
```

To fix this, you could do something like the following:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> str = new ArrayAdapter<>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<>());
idList.setAdapter(str);

for(String userIds : myStrings) {
    query.getInBackground(userIds, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            String name = parseObject.getString("fullname");
            Log.d("These are the names: ", name);

            str.add(name);
        }
    });
}
```

In this code, the adapter is associated with the list synchronously, and asynchronously-retrieved data is then added to the adapter once it is available. Your exact implementation may vary based on how often you are executing this set of queries, but the code above (not compiled, so may contain typos) should illustrate the general principle for you.